# get(0).play() -- Internet Explorer error

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer, video, flowplayer

I have this to show a video modal which works well in all browsers except IE (specifically IE8):

```
//Video
$("#siteNav li.nav5 a").click(function(){
   $("#video").fadeIn();
   $(".commercial").get(0).play();
   return false;
});

$("#video").click(function(event){
   $(this).fadeOut();
   $(".commercial").get(0).pause();
   return false;
});
```

If I click this, IE says "Error on page" and reloads.

If I comment out the line `$(".commercial").get(0).play/pause();` the error doesn't show.

Any ideas how I can write this with an IE-friendly alternative?

I should also mention I use HTML5 video for compatible browsers, and Flowplayer/Flash for IE.

Comment: What is `.commercial` applied to?

Comment: `.commercial` is simply a class i assign to the movie so i can: `$(".commercial").click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});`

Comment: what is that movie? HTML5 Audio/Video? Can you post the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using flowplayer for IE browser then try below code.

```
//Video
$("#siteNav li.nav5 a").click(function(){
   $("#video").fadeIn();
   if($.browser.msie)
     $f($(".commercial").get(0)).play();
   else
     $(".commercial").get(0).play(); 
   return false;
});

$("#video").click(function(event){
   $(this).fadeOut();
   if($.browser.msie)
     $f($(".commercial").get(0)).pause();
   else
     $(".commercial").get(0).pause(); 
   return false;
});
```

Comment: @Yahreen - Try my answer hope that helps

Comment: Could you explain why that is?

Comment: Since you are using flowplayer in case of IE, you have to get the flowplayer instance and then call play/pause method on it. Don't forget to mark this as an answer thanks.

Comment: Ah, thanks. For anyone else looking for more info: http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html#flowplayer